# style not applied for "<rich:dataTable> footer" in IE

Tags: css, jsf, richfaces

I have `rich:dataScoller` inside `rich:dataTable`'s footer and I am trying to override the Style class `rich-table-footer` for the datatable's footer. It is working fine in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE.

**CSS**

```
            .rich-table-footer
            {
                background-color: transparent;
            }
```

**HTML**

```
<rich:dataTable>
.
.
.

<f:facet name="footer">
 <rich:datascroller maxPages="3" ajaxSingle="false" 
     page="#{bean.dataScrollerIndex}"/>
</f:facet>
</rich:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with IE not with RichFaces. By the looks of it IE has problems with transparency. You can try `background: transparent` or setting transparent image for the background.